# How to make custom router login page?

Tags: php, html, login-script

I am trying to make a custom router login page. I want the user to ridirected to the login page when he/she connects to the wifi network. How can i make such a login /registration system?

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is called captive portal.

Wikipedia describes some methods for implementation:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal#Implementation

A PHP implementation can be found here:
http://www.andybev.com/index.php/Using_iptables_and_PHP_to_create_a_captive_portal

Very popular implementation is chillispot (there is also a good description of the technology in the backend):

http://www.chillispot.org/

Often you will also need a capable router e.g. a device that uses open-wrt:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenWrt#